# C# NamedPipe thread safety on async calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, pipe

I wonder how to guarantee thread-safety on pipes during async operations.

For example this code is being executed by a thread (the stream has been created properly before):

```
pipeClientStream.ConnectAsync(cancel).Wait();
```

Meanwhile another thread wants to know if the pipe is (already) connected

```
bool isConnected = pipeClientStream.IsConnected;
```

I didn't find a notice about thread-safety in the microsoft docs, but I guess if it was thread-safe there would be a hint. I also dived into reference source of the Pipe.cs and PipeStream.cs to look for locks but there where none to be found.

So in the end the only "safe" way would be to create a "locked" boolean value set by the thread which is working with the pipe and encapsulate the pipe.

What do you think is proper way of dealing with such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to deal with most non-threadsafe object is to lock it:

```
lock(pipeClientStream){
    return pipeClientStream.IsConnected;
}
```

Locking a shared resource like this is fine, but it it also common to use a separate object to control access to some resource. If you are using actual asynchronous code you might need some other solution.

do not try to create your own "lock" by using any kind of shared boolean. There is a huge risk you will get something wrong and end up with non threadsafe code.

There are also named mutexes if you need synchronization between processes, but that is not needed if you keep to a single process.